# VPN in Powershell

Tags: vpn, automation, powershell, pptp

I am updating an old DOS script which is used to open a Windows PPTP VPN connection between two server, copy some files, then close the connection. I am wanting to rewrite the script in powershell, so I will be able to send an e-mail to notify users if anything goes wrong with the copy.

The current code is as follows

```
rasdial connectionName UserName Password
if not %errorlevel% == 0 goto vpn
```

When I try to use rasdial in powershell, it opens a new window, and powershell doesn't have access to %errorlevel% or $lastexitcode.

Is there a way to have powershell open rasdial in the same window? If not, is there a different utility I can use to open a VPN connection?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you get the exit code:

```
(Start-Process rasdial -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "connectionName UserName Password" -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode
```